# OpenLayers: how to display the character degrees in the label

Tags: openlayers-2, labeling

I would like to display temperature in label. 
So how can I write DEGREE SIGN? to be display as  ° 
I was trying write: 
& # 176; or  & deg; or \ & deg; and nothing. 
Can anybody knows?

I greet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define the label property in style definition like below

```
label: "${text} °C"
```

and done.